# Distribute grids evenly to fit screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i am trying to get three rows in my recyclerview to fit the screen perfectly. In other words distributed evenly with no scrolling. I have a toolbar and a recyclerview with two columns/three rows. As of now i have just set the items height to fit the screen close enough but there has to be a better way?

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="#CCCC"
        android:layout_width= "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/colorBlock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the `RecyclerView` is supposed to be used in situations where recycling views can happen - a.k.a. scrollable because large amount of views. I don't mean to say it can not be used for smaller collections, but there's no value in using it upon other layouts. As a matter of fact, not being built for such scenarios, it becomes very difficult to make use of it in scenarios like in this question. If you absolutely want to use `RecyclerView`, I am not aware of any way to do it in `xml` only. I think you'll have to implement your own layout manager for this.

If you are open to using other layouts, here's a solution involving a bunch of linear layouts and weights. Not optimal, having to use nested weights, but a solution nevertheless:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff000"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0f00"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff00f0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#f0ff00"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0fff00"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00fff0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#f000ff"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0f00ff"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00f0ff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I will try this as i have still not found any solution using recyclerview (does not seem like the way to solve it either). Thanks!